# ASP.NET MVC 3 diplay label + data in readonly scenario using templated HtmlHelpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to display short description like label and near it data associated with this description.
For editing data it looks like

```
<div class="field">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerTaxId)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CustomerTaxId)
</div>
```

Now I want to do the same thing for readonly data. I've written next code

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TotalAmount)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TotalAmount)
</div>
```

It seems working but it breaks semantic meaning of label tag which must be used for input tags only.
Is there a way in MVC 3 to get something like

```
<div>
   <span class="label">Total amount</span>
   <span class="value">1500.00 $</span>
</div>
```

with minimal efforts (think it can be done with heavy template usage)

It seems like I can overwrite template for `Html.DisplayFor` how to deal with `Html.LabelFor`?

Comment: You could create a custom html helper extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom html helper as below,

```
public static MvcHtmlString Span<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
         Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
  var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData, null);
  string spanInnerText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName;

  TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("span");
  tag.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
  tag.SetInnerText(spanInnerText);

  return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

You could use in a view as,

```
@Html.Span(m => m.Name, new { @class = "label" })
```

Comment: `tag.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);` - such extension method is internal so can't use it. As it was recommended I replaced it with
`MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));`

Comment: That's great! I was going through the source code and made the mistake.